# How to update and read a collection in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble with a project I am working on. I want to create a database in which I can store dates and links to YouTube videos in a MongoDB database. I am using Mongoose as the ORM. The problem seems to be that the database and collection is created and I can read and update it outside the routes but not inside (if anyone can understand what I am saying). I want to be able to make a GET request for the current items in the database on the /database route as well as make a POST to the /database route.

My code is below. Please help:

```
//grab express and Mongoose
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create an express app
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('/public/css', {"root": __dirname}));

//create a database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/__dirname/data');

//connect to the data store on the set up the database
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Create a model which connects to the schema and entries collection in the __dirname database
var Entry = mongoose.model("Entry", new Schema({date: 'date', link: 'string'}), "entries");

mongoose.connection.on("open", function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!");
});

//start the server on the port 8080
app.listen(8080);

//The routes

//The route for getting data for the database
app.get("/database", function(req, res) {
    Entry.find({}, function(err, data) {console.log(err, data, data.length); });

});

//The route for posting data on the database
app.post("/database", function(req, res) {
    //test new post
    var newMonth = new Entry({date: '1997-10-30', link: 'https://wwww.youtube.com/'});
        newMonth.save(function(err) {
            if (err !== null) {
                //object was not save
                console.log(err);
                    } else {
                console.log("it was saved!")
        };
    });
});



//create an express route for the home page at http://localhost:8080/
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('ok');
    res.sendFile('/views/index.html', {"root": __dirname + ''});
});

//Send a message to the console
console.log('The server has started');
```

Comment: How are you making these requests? Using curl?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm using Node.js + Mongoose to make the requests as far as I know. Apologies I am a bit of a noob with these things.

Comment: To test the GET and POST routes, you're going to have to pass the GET or POST verb along with the request or the server will have no idea what you want to do with it. Or are you using a form to do so?

Comment: Am I not doing that already? Can you not show me on my code where I should do that and how?

Comment: How are you trying to access your routes? Simply by typing on the address bar of your browser?

Comment: Yes. I type in localhost:8080/ and localhost:8080/database (this is the one I want to handle both the GET and POST requests).

Comment: You can't make a POST request using the address bar. I assume your GET request works though?

Comment: I see what you mean in terms of the post request. I'll be using a form for that one yes. The GET request doesn't seem to be working though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your GET request should have worked because a browser executes a GET request by default. Try the following.

```
app.get("/database", function(req, res) {
    Entry.find(function(err, data) {  
       if(err) {
          console.log(err);
       } else {
          console.log(data);
       }
   });

});
```

As far as testing your POST route is concerned, install a plugin for Google Chrome called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). You can execute all sorts of requests using it. It's great for testing purposes.

Comment: No problem. Also check out Postman like I mentioned earlier. It will make your life a lot easier while performing tests like these.